# How to COMMIT INSERT every 1000 rows

Tags: sql-server

i'm using SQL Server 2019 and i've a giant .SQL file with millions of records to be inserted, when I run it, my memory overflows, "System.OutMemory" was thrown.

I'd like to know how I make every 1000 lines inserted to execute the COMMIT.

I've tried something like this, but I'm not getting it.
Could someone help me please.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLE_NAME](
      [Col_1] [int] NULL,
      [Col_2] [varchar](50) NULL
     ) ON [PRIMARY]
        
        
     DECLARE @CommitSize INT
     SET @CommitSize = 1000
     WHILE @CommitSize = 1000
        
      BEGIN
      BEGIN TRAN
           
        
      INSERT INTO TEST ([Col_1] [Col_2]) VALUES (1, 'Value')
      INSERT INTO TEST ([Col_1] [Col_2]) VALUES (2, 'Value')
      INSERT INTO TEST ([Col_1] [Col_2]) VALUES (3, 'Value')        
      .
      .
      .
      .
      .
      .
      .
        
      Millions Rows
          
  COMMIT TRAN
  END
```

Comment: I don't see where you are incrementing/decrementing `@CommitSize`. Is there relevant code missing in your question? As to your `System.OutMemory` error, it seems you are running from SSMS. Try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` to the beginning of the script. Also, consider running the script with the `SQLCMD` command-line utility instead.

Comment: To be brutally honest, you should consider parsing this giant file into a CSV and use `bcp.exe` or `SqlBulkCopy` to insert it.